# Most prevalent text (most repetitions) based on multiple criteria, using named ranges, transpose and indirect

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am trying to pop-out the most prevalent Company name by using multiple criteria i.e. criteria which may also combine an array of two criteria's within and accordingly show the highest most prevalent location/city name

This is the code I worked on but it doesn't give me the output i'm looking for, rather nothing.

I am looking to show the most prevalent (most repeated) Company based on the formula first filtering myListofCompanies from the main Companies column, then in the Location/City column, it combines to check for two cities together as an array, namely Chicago & New York in that column and then shows me the most prevalent Company Name

**NamedRanges:** 
**Company** = A List of all available companies 
**MyListofCos** = A list of my selected companies i wish to filter the list by
**Location** = a list of location those companies have offices in. Here I want to have two cities as options (for example, check most prevalent for New York and Chicago together) - by using Transpose(Indirect(C27)) which references to {"New York","Chicago"}

The code is a CSE and is used with a CTRL + SHIFT + ENTER

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(Company,MODE.MULT(IF(Company=TRANSPOSE(MyListofCOS),IF(Locations=TRANSPOSE(INDIRECT(C27)),MATCH(Company,Company,0))))),"-")
```

Answer (score 0):

Try...

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(Company,MODE.MULT(IF(ISNUMBER(MATCH(Company,MyListofCos,0)),IF(ISNUMBER(MATCH(Location,{"New York","Chicago"},0)),MATCH(Company,Company,0))))),"-")
```

or

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(Company,MODE.MULT(IF(ISNUMBER(MATCH(Company,MyListofCos,0)),IF(ISNUMBER(MATCH(Location,C27:C28,0)),MATCH(Company,Company,0))))),"-")
```

...where C27 and C28 contain New York and Chicago, respectively.  Note that both formulas need to be confirmed with CONTROL+SHIFT+ENTER.